# Practice Makes It Perfect

Tags: meaning, usage, idioms

Is the phrase "*practice makes perfect*" (three words) a nonstandard but popular variation of "*practice makes* ***it*** *perfect*" (four words)?

Comment: The well-known idiom  *"practice makes perfect"* is grammatically "correct" as is.

Comment: Here's one source with info on that idiom *"practice makes perfect"*:  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Practice+makes+perfect

Comment: It's more or less a single lexical item (despite clearly consisting of three words, morphologically speaking), pre-formed in the lexicon of every native speaker, not formed productively through a set of grammatical rules.  Note, though, that variations may be formed by analogy (which is ultimately how all grammar works): "practice makes permanent", for example.  In any case, there's nothing wrong with the phrase, and its existence in the lexicon blocks the formation of "practice makes it perfect".

Comment: In Short, "it" is not at all required as its reflects the same upon each and everything.

Answer (score 4):

No. "Practice makes perfect" is the correct idiom in common use. You raise a valid question. To be grammatically correct it would have to be "practice makes it perfect" (as you suggest) or "practice makes perfection."

Answer (score 1):

"Practice makes perfect" is a common idiom. It's used for saying that if you repeat an activity or do it regularly, you will become very good at it. It's you that becomes perfect, not the activity that becomes perfect. So the correct phrase is "Practice makes perfect" and it's not idiomatic to say that "Practice makes it perfect". However, grammatically, it also makes sense as one's work improves when it's done repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Think of "perfect" as a pseudo-noun. Or just imagine a city called Perfect. And another one called Nice (no pun intended). And yet another one named Like A Tree.

"This design is far from perfect."
"You have to have more than just materials to make Perfect."
"Go ahead and make Nice with those people."
"Catch the next train to Perfect and make some friends."
"I don't want to make any friends, and I can't make Nice tonight."
"Then why don't you make Like a Tree and get out of my face."

Note that you don't actually physically *make* friends or money or time, i.e. you can't *create* them. "Make" is just a figure of speech in all those cases.